# Referencing TeX itself in an index entry

Tags: indexing

Using the package `makeidx` I'm trying to generate an index entry with `\index{TeX@\TeX}` but it doesn't show up in the index.  This is obviously due to the expansion of `\TeX` but I can't figure out how to make it work.

**Update**: OK, I now see where the problem was and I'll add code to reproduce it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\indexp}[1]{\index{#1}}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\TeX\index{TeX@\TeX}

\pagebreak

\TeX\indexp{TeX@\TeX}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I used my `indexp` command throughout my whole book because I otherwise had problems with index entries from footnotes.  The `\TeX` index entry is generated with `\index` but not with `\indexp`, so it was my fault.  Sorry for the noise.

Still, if someone could explain what exactly the difference is, I'd be thankful.  I aped `\indexp` from somewhere because it solved problems I had but I don't really know how it differs from `\index`.

**Another Update**:

Sorry for the delay, but I was really busy.  Here's a minimal example do demonstrate why I use `\indexp` and not `\index`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\indexp}[1]{\index{#1}}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
The crux of the biscuit is the
apostrophe\index{apostrophe@\textsc{aprostropheA}}.\footnote{Really, it's the
  apostrophe\index{apostrophe@\textsc{aprostropheA}}.}

\pagebreak

The crux of the biscuit is the
apostrophe\indexp{apostropheB@\textsc{aprostropheB}}.\footnote{Really, it's the
  apostrophe\indexp{apostropheB@\textsc{aprostropheB}}.}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

With `\index` I get two different index entries which is obviously not what I want.  With `\indexp` I get one which is fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a short but complete example of code?

Comment: This works without problems for me and shows the output of `\TeX` as expected, both with `makeidx` and `imakeidx`

Comment: I see no real gain in using `\indexp` in place of `\index`, so probably there's more you aren't showing. What's the problem with footnotes?

Answer (score 2):

There are category code changes involved when working with `\index`. As such, and since it seems like you're not doing anything other than passing an argument to `\index` via `\indexp`, use

```
\newcommand{\indexp}{\index}
```

instead of

```
\newcommand{\indexp}[1]{\index{#1}}
```

That way the argument is completely handled by `\index`, not `\indexp`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\indexp}{\index}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\TeX\index{TeX@\TeX}

\pagebreak

\TeX\indexp{TeX@\TeX}

\printindex
\end{document}
```